# Custom partition in pulsar

Tags: apache-pulsar

Unable to send message from producer to pulsar, when Producer is set to customPartition (please refer below code).

```
Producer<byte[]> producer = client.newProducer()
                .topic(pulsarTopic)
                //.messageRoutingMode(MessageRoutingMode.RoundRobinPartition)
                .messageRoutingMode(MessageRoutingMode.CustomPartition)
                .messageRouter( new MessageRounterImpl())
                .create();
```

Code to send Message :

```
 producer.send(msg);
```

MessageRouterImpl has randomly generates number with range from 0 to 5, as below code

```
public class MessageRounterImpl  implements MessageRouter {
@Override
public int choosePartition(Message<?> msg, TopicMetadata metadata) {
   Random r = new Random();
   return r.nextInt((0 - 5) + 1);
   
}
```

}

**My question is why i am unable to send message from producer with *CustomPartition* and why i am getting below log messages**

> Batching the messages from the batch container from timer thread
>
> Batching the messages from the batch container with 0 messages

With MessageRoutingMode.RoundRobinPartition and MessageRoutingMode.SinglePartition I was able to send message from producer.

It would be really helpful if someone through light on this .

Answer (score 1):

First, please take into account that [partitioned topics](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/next/concepts-messaging/#partitioned-topics) should be **explicitly** created before a publisher starts sending messages, for example:

```
bin/pulsar-admin topics create-partitioned-topic persistent://tenant/namespace/partitioned-topic-name --partitions 5
```

Second, the following line will throw an exception (it cannot handle negative values as input):

```
return r.nextInt((0 - 5) + 1);
```

It is possible to use the following one:

```
return r.nextInt(5);
```